# What should my placeholders be for my TensorFlow regression with multiple features?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, linear-regression

Hi, I'm trying to run Linear Regression using TensorFlow so I [took this code](https://github.com/nethsix/gentle_tensorflow/blob/master/code/linear_regression_multi_feature_using_mini_batch_with_tensorboard.py) and wish to fit my own dataset X_train (43, 5) and y_train (43,). Here's my code:

```js
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = numpy.random

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

# Data
train_X = X_train
train_Y = y_train
test_X = X_test
test_Y = y_test

n_samples = train_X.shape[0]
row = train_X.shape[0]
column = train_X.shape[1]

print(row, column)

# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [row, column])
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
#W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
#b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([column, 1]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="bias")

# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)

# Gradient descent
#  Note, minimize() knows to modify W and b because Variable objects are trainable=True by default
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y:train_Y})
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
                "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')

    # Graphic display
    plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.plot(train_X, sess.run(W) * train_X + sess.run(b), label='Fitted line')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    print("Testing... (Mean square loss Comparison)")
    testing_cost = sess.run(
        tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred - Y, 2)) / (2 * test_X.shape[0]),
        feed_dict={X: test_X, Y: test_Y})  # same function as cost above
    print("Testing cost=", testing_cost)
    print("Absolute mean square loss difference:", abs(
        training_cost - testing_cost))

    plt.plot(test_X, test_Y, 'bo', label='Testing data')
    plt.plot(train_X, sess.run(W) * train_X + sess.run(b), label='Fitted line')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I tried to [follow this](https://medium.com/all-of-us-are-belong-to-machines/gentlest-intro-to-tensorflow-part-3-matrices-multi-feature-linear-regression-30a81ebaaa6c) to match the dimensions

But I keep getting this error: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 43 and 5 for 'Mul_18' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [43,5], [5,1]. Setting the placeholders to random solves this issue but then triggers another dimensional error at any of the lines: sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y:train_Y}). Some one please help!?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do matrix multiplication. So you should make use of [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul).

The operation of [`tf.multiply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply) does elementwise multiplication for which both the tensor's shapes must be same.